# Fix for 404 error while opening JupyterLab in Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I recently installed Anaconda on Windows 10 for data science. Everything is working fine, except for JupyterLab. when I try to launch it with any of these methods [git bash - cmd - powershell - anaconda navigator] I get the same `404:page not found` error.

I updated nodejs package as some answers suggested, but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab --user`

Then:
`conda install -c conda-forge nodejs`

If that does not work try:
`jupyter lab build`

Comment: Tried both, but still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try 
    ```conda install -c conda-forge jupyter``` and then ```conda install notebook```
    Change the default directory inside C:\Users\USERNAME.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py.
    Find and edit this line to c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:/Your/Path'

Comment: I don't have any .py files inside the .jupyter folder. All I could find is .json files, 2 files exactly. I opened them and looked for the line you mentioned, but both of the files has it.